# Export CSV/XLSX using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export, laravel-5.4

my post is too long but pls help me !

I tried to export data from database to CSV file, but I got 2 problems:

**1. Update: I solved it by changing CSV to XLSX.**

**2. How can I get title_name in eloquent ? I tried but it did not work.**

```
$title_japan = TitleJapan::select('id','name',$this->title->name)->get();
```

**Here is my TitleJapan model:**

```
    class TitleJapan extends Model
{
    public function title()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Title');
    }
}
```

**Here is my Title model:**

```
    class Title extends Model
{
    public function titleJapan()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TitleJapan');
    }

}
```

**And my controller:**

```
    class ExportController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('Export.index');
    }

    public function exportTitleCSV()
    {
        $title = Title::all();
        $title_japan = TitleJapan::select('id','name',$this->title->name)->get();

        return Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use ($title,$title_japan,$title_oversea) {

            $excel->setTitle('TitleBandai');
            $excel->sheet('FirstSheet', function($sheet) use($title_japan) {
                $sheet->fromArray($title_japan);
            });
            $excel->sheet('SecondSheet', function($sheet) use($title_oversea) {
                $sheet->fromArray($title_oversea);
            });

        })->export('csv');
    }
}
```

**File CSV I got**

[image]

**File CSV I want**

[image]

Comment: First I would try exporting as a `xls` or `xlsx` A csv is just a text file and will not understand multiple sheets

Comment: csv files can't have sheets. That's excel only

Comment: Thanks a lot you guys, i solved it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .csv file is very simple. It's just some data separated by commas or some other delimiter. Therefore, it cannot have multiple sheets. If you export as .xlsx it should work.

For the name of the title, i suggest you eager load the title and then process the result into an array.